# Relationship between IBM & Lenovo

Tags: thinkpad, lenovo-laptop, ibm-server

What is the relationship Lenovo and IBM? Is IBM the manufacturer of Lenovo computers?

Comment: IBM no longer makes desktops or laptops.  They sold that business to Lenovo many years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Briefly, they are separate. IBM sold PC and Laptop business to Lenovo and focuses on consulting services now. IBM no longer manufactures personal computers.